# How to Convert mysql rows to columns which do not have tags

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql Table with rows, which is basically in and out time of user, but it does not have any tag for which row is In and which is Out.

Only way to find out is taking min and max time for each date for each user and then selecting them in two columns. But I am having very hard time to achieve this.. Please help

```
My current data looks like this:

+-----------+--------------+-----------------------+
| "User Id" | Date         | "Time"                |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------+
| userA     | "2019-04-22" | "2019-04-22 08:48:23" |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------+
| userA     | "2019-04-22" | "2019-04-22 17:47:51" |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------+
| userB     | "2019-04-22" | "2019-04-22 08:19:52" |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------+
| userB     | "2019-04-22" | "2019-04-22 18:06:27" |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------+
| userC     | "2019-04-22" | "2019-04-22 08:27:28" |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------+
| userc     | "2019-04-22" | "2019-04-22 17:19:25" |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------------+

Desired Output is This:
+--------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| Userid | Date         | InTime                | OutTime               |
+--------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| userA  | "2019-04-22" | "2019-04-22 08:48:23" | "2019-04-22 17:47:51" |
+--------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| userB  | "2019-04-22" | "2019-04-22 08:19:52" | "2019-04-22 18:06:27" |
+--------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| userC  | "2019-04-22" | "2019-04-22 08:27:28" | "2019-04-22 17:19:25" |
+--------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `min()` and `max()` with `group by`

```
select Userid , Date, min(`time`) as intime,max(`time`) as outtime
from tablename
group by Userid , Date
```

Comment: No it didn't. The issue is "does not have any tag for which row is In and which is Out" - this is the (trivial) XY problem.